# Uninstall Python Compiled App on Debian

Tags: debian, python, compiling, uninstall

So ages ago I knew how to do this but now I have forgot the last command.

So for some odd reason alot of python apps I compile to the system *and not just python apps* don´t have uninstall options in the MAKEFILE. So someone told me to run `python setup.py install --record installed-locations.txt` instead of the usuall `python setup.py install`. I am awear I could go and look at that text file and delete each file manually with rm but I remember there was a command that ould look into that text file and automaticly remove them for me. The issue is I don´t remember this command.

Does anyone know what command I am talking about or know of a command that could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. `cat files.txt | xargs rm -rf`

So in summory to uninstall apps from system compiled with python follow these steps

**1)**
Download the source code for the exsact version of said app if you do not have it already

**2)**
Extract the file and cd into the extracted files

**3)** Run as root `python setup.py install --record files.txt`

**4)** Now run as root `cat files.txt | xargs rm -rf`

The application should now be uninstalled. If need be go clean up all the config and setting files in your home directory to regain some more space.